# How to i create a for loop for a indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)

Tags: java

I need this piece of code to search for the specified string, and when it finds one it outputs, and then keeps looking for more.

```
  int FoundPsn = sample.indexOf("quick", 0);
  System.out.print("sample.indexOf(\"quick\") = " + FoundPsn);
```

Comment: What does the second argument of `indexOf()` mean? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int- If you think about what that second index means, you can think about how to make a loop on it. Also, you can put other kinds of condition than `index < limit` in a `for` loop, such as `for (int pos = sample.indexOf(searchTerm); pos >= 0; pos = sample.indexOf(searchTerm, pos + searchTerm.length()) {`(or you might use `++pos` as the looping expression). Also, your variable `FoundPsn` is not in line with the Java Coding Conventions.

Comment: i don't know what to write in the for()

Comment: @JuanHerrera what research tells you to use a for loop?

Comment: @LewBloch it looks for the index of the word "quick" in the sentence and it prints it out

Comment: @JonnyHenly i need to keep looking for the desired string in a sentence, if there are more

Comment: To those that answered my question - I know what it means. It is a challenge for the OP to think about what it means. Not just the Javadoc definition, but what does it imply? What are the consequences?

Comment: @JuanHerrera for loops are generally used when a range is involved, while loops are generally used when a condition is involved. A while loop would be better suited for this task, the possible condition being `while(FoundPsn != -1) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index of method working :

```
Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring, starting at the specified index.
The returned index is the smallest value k for which:

 k >= fromIndex && this.startsWith(str, k)
```

If no such value of k exists, then -1 is returned.

Sourdes Java doc : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)

You can do is keep loop until it hits -1 like.

```
int FoundPsn = sample.indexOf("quick");
while(FoundPsn != -1) {
    System.out.println("sample.indexOf(\"quick\") = " + FoundPsn);
    FoundPsn = sample.indexOf("quick", FoundPsn+1);
}
```

Note : This will hit index out of bounds if you are searching of only one char and if it happens to be the last one.

Comment: Yeah after executing, eclipse is really slow

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that:

```
    String sample = "quick, that was quick, and maybe quicker!";
    int foundPsn = 0;
    int startSearch = 0;
    String search = "quick";
    while ((foundPsn = sample.indexOf(search, startSearch)) >= 0){
        System.out.println("sample.indexOf(\"quick\") = " + foundPsn);
        startSearch = foundPsn + search.length();
    }
```